# detect misfire instruction on spring integrations

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using the spring integration to schedule to differnt jobs. I have different triggers and I am seeing the triggers missing execution, but could not find any entry in the log file. I need to log the misfire details in my log file. Could you please let me know how to do it? Also is there a way to provide misfire instruction on spring integration. The pool size is set as 10 so it may be missing the execution because thread is not available, but I am not able to trace it as not entry is available on log file.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Integration uses `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` with this options by default:

```
BeanDefinition scheduler = BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.class)
                .addPropertyValue("poolSize", IntegrationProperties.getExpressionFor(IntegrationProperties.TASK_SCHEDULER_POOL_SIZE))
                .addPropertyValue("threadNamePrefix", "task-scheduler-")
                .addPropertyValue("rejectedExecutionHandler", new CallerRunsPolicy())
                .addPropertyValue("errorHandler", new RootBeanDefinition(MessagePublishingErrorHandler.class))
                .getBeanDefinition();

        registry.registerBeanDefinition(IntegrationContextUtils.TASK_SCHEDULER_BEAN_NAME, scheduler);
```

The `MessagePublishingErrorHandler` sends problems to the global `errorChannel` by default.

If you would like to change some behavior for this global `TaskScheduler`, you should declare your own `taskScheduler` with appropriate options.

Otherwise I don't understand your question and you should provide some more info about the problem.

Comment: I have scheduler multiple jobs cron triggers but some jobs are not getting triggered. It may be due to the resource availability or some other reasons. I need to know the reason why the jobs are missing the trigger. I was wondering whether there is any way to log the misfire details if a misfire happens? Also if I have no mentioned the pool size what will be default pool size it will take?

Comment: Still don't understand. Maybe some code would be helpful?

Comment: Are you sure that you really talk about Spring Integration Framework: http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/ ?

Comment: Yes I am talking about Spring integration. I borrowed the concept of mistrigger from quartz. I will explain I have three jobs. Two jobs run every 20 mins and one run every hour. If the hourly jobs take more time I am seeing the 20 mins job is not running. I am not able find any trace from log file why it is not running. I suspect it may be due to task executed  pool thread pool full, but the thread dump shows the task executor  is waiting. So I want to know how I can find exact reason. Is there a way to log the reason

Comment: The code into the studio! How do you suppose we should reproduce the issue? I still don't see anything related to the EIP though...